# Grab image url's then export to a list

Tags: python

I have code below and it will download the image but all I want is to be able to take the image url and export it into a file. Can you point me in the right direction?

```
 try:
    from urlparse import urljoin
except ImportError:
    from urllib.parse import urljoin

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Scraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.visited = set()
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.session.headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36"}

        requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()  # turn off SSL warnings

    def visit_url(self, url, level):
        print(url)
        if url in self.visited:
            return

        self.visited.add(url)

        content = self.session.get(url, verify=False).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")

        for img in soup.select("img[src]"):
            image_url = img["src"]
```

Comment: How is exporting the image into a file different than downloading it?

Comment: I don't believe it is. However I don't want to download the image. I just want the url to be exported to a file and all url's need to go to a file

Comment: Oh, so you're putting just the URL in the file? Not the image? I must have misread your question then.

Comment: Yes. I just want the URL either printed to the console or each url exported into a single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But the code you provided doesn't download an image. It downloads an html file and extracts image urls, but the code does nothing with extracted image urls.

To make `Scraper.visit_url` to print image urls you have to change only the last line. Here you are:

```
try:
    from urlparse import urljoin
except ImportError:
    from urllib.parse import urljoin

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Scraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.visited = set()
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.session.headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36"}

        requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()  # turn off SSL warnings

    def visit_url(self, url, level):
        print(url)
        if url in self.visited:
            return

        self.visited.add(url)

        content = self.session.get(url, verify=False).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")

        for img in soup.select("img[src]"):
            print(img["src"])
```